# JTable not updating added rows by using repaint() method

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my UI I am using a JTable with a TableModel.In a update method of the implemented Observer interface i am calling the repaint method.The  delete operations take place immediately while on adding  a row it is not updated,but it is updated while switching through tabs( which calls another method instead of repaint)

This is  code for update method:

```
 public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        ((MyTableModel)table_.getModel()).addTableRow(row);

    //addTable(row) adds the  row to the dataVector that populates the JTable
    //the dataVector is updated with added row

            table_.repaint();

            }
```

I wanted to know why the JTable is not getting updated
Please Note->the data Vector has the required rows including the added row

Comment: Repaint should not be necessary.  There is something wrong with your model. It isn't notifying the view of the addition.  You'll have to post code for the model to get a useful answer.  If you're not inheriting from `DefaultTableModel`, you should look at its code to see how change events are fired and do the same in your model.

Comment: thanks,it works now,i added fireTableRowsInserted method instead of repaint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `addTableRow` method should also fire an event indicating the row has been added to alert the `JTable` of this change. Then there is no need for the `repaint` call.

Take for example a look at the implementation of the `addRow` method of the `DefaultTableModel`:

```
public void insertRow(int row, Vector rowData) {
    dataVector.insertElementAt(rowData, row);
    justifyRows(row, row+1);
    fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
}
```

You can clearly see that an event is fired, and no repaint needed. This is all explained in more detail in the [`JTable` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire)

Comment: If you have multiple rows also insert them and call the fireTableRowsInserted() and pass the parameters appropiately